# OpenApi 3.0 SpringBoot Controller use

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi, openapi-generator

Using the openapi maven plugin:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and generating spring boot controllers using a pom config like:

```xml
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
        <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>spring-server</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <!-- specify the swagger yaml -->
              <inputSpec>${project.resources[0].directory}/pet-store.yaml</inputSpec>
              <!-- target to generate java client code -->
              <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
              <!-- pass any necessary config options -->
              <configOptions>
                <serializableModel>true</serializableModel>
                <snapshotVersion>true</snapshotVersion>
              </configOptions>

            </configuration>
          </execution>

        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

will generate a controller like this:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("${openapi.openAPIPetstore.base-path:/v2}")
public class StoreApiController implements StoreApi {

    private final NativeWebRequest request;

    @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
    public StoreApiController(NativeWebRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<NativeWebRequest> getRequest() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(request);
    }

}
```

This is great, but how do I bind in to this to add the business logic without changing the actual generated code? If I extend the controller to add the business logic I get all kinds of issues.

How are you supposed to use this generated code, to extend it to add the correct business logic without changing the generated code which would be bad.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came across your question as I was trying to cope with OAS 3.0 and therefore using the mentioned `openapi-generator-maven-plugin`. Meanwhile I got it to generate exactly what you are describing.

I would suggest dealing with this by

1. generating your model and API classes to a **separate package** from your code and
2. configuring Spring's `@ComponentScan` annotation to not include the generated classes (either with the `basePackages` property alone or combining it with the explicit `excludeFilters` property).

And yes, modifying generated classes is bad. I'd just use them as a starting point for creating your actual controllers.

***Amendment:*** After configuring the code generation in various ways I found the best solution to have only the API (interfaces) being created. This way I can implement my controller without having another implementation interfering with it.

To achieve this my plugin config now looks like this (using the `configOptions/interfaceOnly` option):

```
            <plugin>
                <!-- generate REST API from spec -->
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/api.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <generateModels>true</generateModels>
                            <generateApis>true</generateApis>
                            <generateApiDocumentation>true</generateApiDocumentation>
                            <generateSupportingFiles>true</generateSupportingFiles>
                            <modelPackage>example.openapi.model</modelPackage>
                            <apiPackage>example.openapi.api</apiPackage>
                            <package>example.openapi</package>
                            <output>${generated.sources.restapi.dir}</output>
                            <configOptions>
                                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                                <dateLibrary>java8-localdatetime</dateLibrary>
                                <java8>true</java8>
                                <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks! the config I was missing was the <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>. That was what I was looking for.

Comment: Hi @tim82, I am facing issues, my springboot is not loading the generated classes, have you faced this kind of problem?

Comment: @tim82 and how did you import your generated interfaces to be visible in main app swagger UI v3 ? In my app I couldn't see `v2/api-docs`, only see `/v3/api-docs`